# Random cutouts with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

All I'm trying to do is to get random cutouts (different shapes) via HTML Canvas element.

On the page I have a DIV, and above it I have the canvas element. So far I was able to color the element and cut out the first piece (not random), and wipe/clean the canvas again, but when I'm trying to do the exact same thing multiple times, it wouldn't work :/

Here is the half-working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/a5UAutd2jNgHMTtPMsp4

```
    var cutThatOut = function(coords) {

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

      coords.forEach(function(coord, i){
        if (i==0) {
          ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
        } else {
          ctx.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
        }
      });
      ctx.fill();
    }
```

thanks for your time/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several fixes:

- Start your new set of path commands with `ctx.beginPath`. Otherwise your previous sets of drawing commands will be repeated along with the newest set.
- Make sure you reset compositing at the end of `cutThatOut`. Otherwise your next fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height) will "erase" the whole canvas because it's still using 'destination-out'.
- If you want to do a completely new cutout with each call to cutThatOut then refill the canvas with black at the start of cutThatOut

Just a note: Your random coordinates often cause intersecting sides of the polygon and often extend outside the boundaries of the canvas.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var cutThatOut = function(coords) {

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

  ctx.beginPath();
  coords.forEach(function(coord, i){
    if (i==0) {
      ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
    }
  });
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

}

var wipeIt = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
}

var getRand = function(min, max) {return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);}

cutThatOut([
  {x:c.width/2, y:0},
  {x:c.width,y:c.height/2},
  {x:c.width/2,y:c.height},
  {x:0, y:c.height/2}
]);

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
  wipeIt();
  cutThatOut([
    {x:getRand(1,200), y:getRand(1,200)},
    {x:getRand(1,200), y:getRand(1,200)},
    {x:getRand(1,200), y:getRand(1,200)},
    {x:getRand(1,200), y:getRand(1,200)}
  ]);
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
.adiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adiv">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<p>
  <button id="btn">NEXT!</button>
</p>
```

Comment: works like a charm. thank you very much. this was just a simplified version of what I need to do, but collision might still be an issue.